# Know if an object has sub properties in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm, syntax

How do I know if an arbitrary object has *any* properties in PHP?

I need it for a recursive search on JSON objects as a break condition
i.e break search when the object has no more sub-objects.

I thought of *property_exists* but it checks a *particular* property, while I want to know if *any* property exists.

Answer (score 2):

The function [`get_object_vars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) will return a list of all accessible properties on an object.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use this function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php

From the docs:

> Returns an associative array of defined object accessible non-static properties for the specified object in scope. If a property has not been assigned a value, it will be returned with a NULL value.

You can also use the ReflectionClass to get the object properties like this:

```
$obj = new YourObjectClass;
$reflect = new ReflectionClass($obj);
$props = $reflect->getProperties();

foreach ($props as $prop) {
    print $prop->getName() . "\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [use a foreach loop](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php):

```
foreach (new object as $prop => $value) {
    echo "property \$$prop is $value\n";
}
```

Also You can do it conveniently with [`get_object_vars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php):

```
$propertyName = key(get_object_vars($object));
```

Answer (score 0):

Casting the object to an array and performing a count on the resulting array will tell you if an object has properties.

```
$foo = new Bah();

$propertiesAsArray = (array) $foo;

if(count($propertiesAsArray)) {

    //this object has properties

} else {

   //this object does not have properties
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use :

```
 if(isset($yourobject)){
   //YourCode
 }
```

in a loop to see if the object have anything already set.